# Does this method have a method?

Tags: javascript

I have a few questions about some code I've come across. You're not required to understand the framework or it's API as my only issue is having a better understanding of some concepts.

I understand that in the line below, the variable polygonCollisionSpite is being assigned the return value of game.add.sprite() which I'm assuming is an object.

```
 var polygonCollisionSprite = game.add.sprite(400,128,'check');
```

What's confusing to me is what appears to be method chaining? I'd understand a regular method like game.add() but game.add.sprite(), how does that look in the object? this.game.add.sprite = function(){} ?

Then I also came across

```
 scoreText = game.add.text(10, 10, 'Hit Space to Restart Demo');
 scoreText.font = 'Arial Black';
 scoreText.fontSize = 16;
 scoreText.stroke = '#000';
 scoreText.strokeThickness = 3;
 scoreText.fill = '#fff';
```

This looks like properties are being added to the object returned and assigned to "scoreText". How are properties able to be added without the usage of the .prototype method?

What might the object being returned to scoreText look like?

Finally, an unrelated but simple question: What's the benefit of assigning a fired function to a variable like:

```
myvar = test();
```

Thanks

Comment: Is `add` an `object` or a `method`?

Comment: `var game = {add : {sprite : function () { … }, player : function () { … }, …}, remove : …, …};`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's confusing to me is what appears to be method chaining?

There is no chaining there.

Chaining is when a method returns `this` so `foo.bar().baz()` has the value of `foo` as the value of `this` in both functions.

> ```
> game.add.sprite(400,128,'check');
> ```

This is just accessing properties of an object.

An object can have a property:

```
someObject.someProperty
```

The property can have a value

```
someObject.someProperty = someOtherObject;
```

That value can be an object, which can have its own properties.

> This looks like properties are being added to the object returned and assigned to "scoreText".

The object returned is assigned to `scoreText`. Properties are then added to that object.

> How are properties able to be added without the usage of the .prototype method?

Adding properties to the prototype object makes them available down the inheritance chain when a `new` object is created from the constructor.

You can add properties to any object.

*Most* JavaScript that adds properties to something does it to an object directly and doesn't touch the prototype object.

```
var myPeople = {};
myPeople.john = { name: "John Smith", address: "27 Witherson Ave" };
myPeople.daisy = { name: "Daisy Mannors", address: "19 Cumberbund Rd" };
```

> What might the object being returned to scoreText look like?

There isn't really anything in the code you've provided that could help us infer that. (Other then the properties you explicitly add afterwards).

> Finally, an unrelated but simple question: What's the benefit of assigning a fired function to a variable

The same as using a variable for absolutely anything else. You can reuse it, you can change it, you don't need to type out everything needed to recreate it everytime you want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What I would assume is going on here is `game.add.sprite` works a little bit like the following:

```
game.add.sprite = function (options) {
    // create instance of Sprite
    var inst = new Sprite(options);

    // add inst to some entity pool
    game.objects.push(inst);

    // return for use
    return inst;
};
```

This way, both you and the library/framework has access to this object (inst), and any changes you make, the library/framework is aware of as well.